# though 301 website redirect from .de to .com, google indexes .de Website

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, redirects, search-engine-indexing

I had a website `example.de` . Than I changed the domain with `example.com` . I added example.com also in google search console and than I did every steps in https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en .

I did this 2 months ago. I know, that google needs 180 days to update index, but indexed links in 2 Months have increased instead of decrease.

I checked today `example.de` in google and I found example.de Homepage in Google index, that is TODAY indexed. It looks like in google index so:

```
Title       : current title of example.com - example.com
url         : example.de
Description : current description of example.com
```

I cannot understand, how this is possible. Why Title and Description of example.com and URL of `example.de`?

301 redirect from `example.de` to `example.com` does work very well. I checked it also in Google Search Console with "Fetch as Google" everything works. But `example.de` Website indexed pages in Google are more and more.

Is this some Bug?

Comment: How are you determining that the `example.de` URL is indexed, and not the `example.com` URL? Are you doing an organic search, or using the `site:` operator?

Comment: both URLs are indexed, but I **don't** want to have example.de also in google index. 
If I do organic search `example.de` or use `site:example.de` , I see many indexed pages of example.de  .  But they have in google index same title and description, as example.com indexed Pages. Though example.de is blank Website and  has 301 redirect to example.com .

Comment: Make double sure that the 301 redirects are working for all redirected URLs - Just In Case. If the redirects are working okay, then it will just take time. Google will simply reindex your site at  it's own pace. You cannot count on Google Search Console for timely information. Much  the changes you see happened some time ago and is in no way real-time.

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us the link to your website.

Comment: @nikant25 - sorry, but I cannot write my Website link.

Comment: @closetnoc - okay. I wrote in my Question above, that I did every steps in  "Change of address tool in Search Console" successful.  But I cannot understand, why are number of indexed links of [example.de](http://example.de) are increasing, instead of decrease.  Can I do something more to fix this index problem?

Comment: Again, Google Search Console is often quite a bit behind. So an increase is not alarming to me. This is common.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the results from example.de in the search results? Do they redirect you to the new correct page on example.com? Also make sure you redirect all known urls to new domain, then to be sure you try to "catch all" so you are sure you have redirects on everything. If you miss redirects on some important pages which also have strong backlinks from other websites you might have to wait much longer for the results to appear.